# Создание кук при перезагрузке страницы(laravel)

Tags: laravel, cookie

Доброго дня. Имеется следующая непонятная ситуация. Есть сайт - `site.com`, сессии хранятся в куках, домен для кук `.site.com`. Если пользователь не залогинен, то при каждом обновлении страницы создаётся кука, пример куки:

```
name:74d8921dc9cd946e78acf39aad1f6ba8b76b4ee8
content: 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%3D
```

Вскоре, пользователь получает ошибку 400. Я брал создаваемую куку и выводил её значение, оно равно  `null` , получается laravel  создаёт пустые куки. Если в middlware WEB, закоментить строку

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
```

проблема исчезает. Но я не уверен, стоит ли отключать шифрование кук, особенно когда они используются для сессий.
В общем, как это всё побороть?

Comment: session не хранятся в куках,они хранятся на сервере,а cookie храниться в браузере.Session используют cookie для идентификации пользователя.Ничего отключать не надо.лучше поподробней опишите что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, есть три сайта, site.com , sub1.site.com , sub2..site.com.
Единыя авторизация проходит на sub1.site.com, В session.php ` 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie'),` На  поддоменах, в принципе, только зарегистрированные пользователи, На основном домене site.com пользователи могут быть и не авторизированные, Но если пользователь не авторизирован на site.com, то при каждом обновлении страницы создаются куки, что в итоге ведёт к переполнению.и ошибке 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалась, проблема была в двойном вызове `middleware web`. Как оказалось, с последней версией он вызывается автоматически. Удаление этого `middleware` из `routes.php` решило все, а еще пришлось обновить ларавель и обязательно проверить `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, так должен быть такой код

```
/**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
        ], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
```